# is it required to store QR codes in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, qr-code

I have a requirement in my project where I need to generate QR Code for every user who uses our application. Initially I thought I will generate the QR code which will have UserID encoded in the image and the QR image will be stored in a database table column. This stored QR image will be shown to user which he can print when ever required. But later I found that, each and every time I can just generate the QR code for the user and show it to him (as the UserID will never change), instead of generating, saving and retrieving it from Database. What will be the best practice???

Did any one come across this situation? I don't see any need to store the QR Code image file in database, instead I can generate it on the fly and show it to the user. But still I would like to get some guidance or ideas from people based on their experiences.

Comment: why generate it all the time.Instead save it once not in db but in server i would say and show it user when asked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say generate it each time. Image files take up a lot of space and it's just another representation of the userid, basically duplicate data.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoelFan, I have decided to generate it each time when ever required.